# My baked maps are glitched

Tags: baking

If i bake a map the colour of the parts are red and black or pink and black.[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use multiple materials? Have you added the baking image texture node to all of them? Do you have multiple objects or UVs sharing these materials that could overlap on the UV space?

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16dguqrFBY7Yvh7izOTCtIjQX_vm1DCrB/view?usp=drive_link thats the blender file if thats is what you need

Comment: that's it but your link asks for an authorization, could you please fix that or use another platform?

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.com to upload your blend file to your question or provide more detailed screenshots on your material baking set up.

Comment: Hello, Imagineniv .. welcome to BSE. Could you flesh this post out a bit, with details of _what_  you are trying to bake .. diffuse color.. combined.. etc, ? That would tell us more about why the monochrome image is unexpected.

Comment: If you're trying to bake the diffuse, it won't be possible if you are using Metallic in the Principled BSDF

Comment: iam using metallic in one of my mapsbut the other one with wood texture has the same problem.

Comment: i tried removing metallic from the Principled BSDF but it didnt work

Comment: I don't know how Combine is supposed to work but he Diffuse works fine: https://zupimages.net/up/23/43/9tsp.jpg

Comment: i dont know what i did but if i do just the difuuse it doesnt work. Can it be a problemwith the pc ? bECAUSE i even tried with file i uploaded but it doesnt work.